# How to find the maxima and minima of discontinous function?

Tags: derivatives, matlab

I have some data and it looks like Sawtooth wave and I have to find out the distance between two consecutive peaks and for this purpose, I am trying to calculate derivative and then finding out distance between two minimas. Please suggest, what should be the appropriate way to calculate the distance between consecutive peaks.[image]

Comment: I must be really stupid, but is the function pictured above discontinuous? :-)

Comment: @Adam: I do not think you are stupid.

Comment: That´s nice to know. What do you think about the continuity of the function?

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the distance between two peaks instead calculating the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]For a discontinuous function $ f(a)=>f(a+h) & f(a)=>f(a-h) $ ,then f(x) has maxima at x=a.

$ f(a)<=f(a+h) & f(a)<=f(a-h)$  ,then f(x) has minima at x=a .

Where h is a very small value and a is constant.

These are condition for maxima and minima in a discontinous function graph.

Comment: So you are basically saying that if you go from a point a little to the left or to the right and get smaller values you are looking at a maximum, right? That seems like a definition of a local maximum and it doesn´t seem to be valid only for discontinuous functions.

Comment: You can't differentiate if it is discontinous.But you can find the maxima and minima using these defintion :) I have added a picture to make myself more clear.

Comment: Could you suggest me any computation technique in Matlab for calculating it.