# How to find the global minimum or maximum of a data set

Tags: optimization

From some experiment, I am getting noisy data. I am interested in highest maximum value from data. Somehow data is periodic and I want to get the highest maximum value from first period. I am quite new in this area, Please suggest me any reading material or how can I solve it in Matlab.
Plot of data can be found here: [How to find the maxima and minima of discontinous function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562633/how-to-find-the-maxima-and-minima-of-discontinous-function)

In above mentioned plot, data is smooth and it is easy to find highest maximum value. After smoothing of data there would be few maximum values and that's why I am looking for global maximum. I do not want to truncate the data and look for maximum value in a specific place.

Comment: just use the $\max$ command in matlab 8)

Comment: I have mentioned that data is periodic and I do not want to truncate part of data. I am also interested maximum value from first period.